# How to create Azure devops code review policy

Tags: tfs

How to create a code review policy on azure devops TFSVC repository? We want to make the code review mandatory for developers so code check-in is possible on successful review. We use TfsVc branches and not planning to migrate to git.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to make the code review mandatory for TFVS repository.

The code review capabilities of TFVC are very limited.
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs?view=azure-devops